# SWT -First radio button always gets focus in RCP 4x version

Tags: button, focus, rcp, e4

First radio button control inside dialog always gets focus inside a Composite in RCP 4.x version.Even though we try to set focus to first label, its not gaining focus. In RCP 3.X version,label is getting focus and first radio button is not getting selected. How to overcome this and set focus to first label instead of radio.

PFB the sample code which we tried in 3.x version where first radio button is not getting selected automatically.

```java
@Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {

        Composite composite = new Composite(parent,SWT.CENTER);
        composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.NONE, SWT.NONE, true, true));
          ((GridData) composite.getLayoutData()).minimumWidth = 200;

          paintGroup(composite);
          ABC.forceFocus();
          return parent;
    }
    private void paintGroup(Composite parent)
    {
         Group group = new Group(parent, SWT.NONE);
          group.setText("Type 1");
            GridLayout groupGridLayout = new GridLayout(1, false);
            group.setLayout(groupGridLayout);
            GridData groupGridData = new GridData(SWT.NONE, SWT.NONE, true, true);
            groupGridData.widthHint = 200;
            groupGridData.heightHint = 40;
            group.setLayoutData(groupGridData);
        Composite mainComposite = new Composite(group,SWT.CENTER);
     mainComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, false));
     mainComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.NONE, SWT.NONE, true, true));
       Button abcRadio = new Button(mainComposite, SWT.RADIO);
         ABC = new Label(mainComposite, 
                SWT.NONE);
        GridData gDataLabel = new GridData(SWT.NONE, SWT.NONE, true, true);
        gDataLabel.verticalAlignment = SWT.CENTER;
        ABC.setText(" " + "ABC");
        ABC.setLayoutData(gDataLabel);
        Button defRadio = new Button(mainComposite, SWT.RADIO);
        Label DEF = new Label(mainComposite, 
                SWT.NONE);
        GridData gDataLabel1 = new GridData(SWT.NONE, SWT.NONE, true, true);
        gDataLabel1.verticalAlignment = SWT.CENTER;
        DEF.setText(" " + "DEF");
        DEF.setLayoutData(gDataLabel1);
       abcRadio.setSelection(false);
      defRadio.setSelection(false);
}
```

We used the same code in 4.x version and first radio button is always selected when dialog is opened.

Comment: `Label` controls generally can't have focus so I don't see how this ever worked. `setFocus` returns `true` if it works, what are you getting? There isn't any difference between SWT in RCP 3 and 4 (just a newer version). Show us a [mre]

Comment: In RCP 3, internally control is going to Label(Control).setFocus whereas in RCP 4, its going internally to Composite.setFocus and ultimately first control in Composite which is a radio button is getting focus.Same code is reused in RCP 3 and RCP 4,but while opening dialog, control goes to first radio button and it is getting selected in RCP 4. In  RCP 3,when dialog opens, first radio control is not getting selected automatically.Radio button selection is set as false.

Comment: Also, if we try to add any new button inside Composite in RCP4, focus goes to that button and radio button is not getting selected. But what we need is radio button should not get selected automatically even if it is the first control in RCP E4.

Comment: You could try using a `Text` control with SWT.READ_ONLY style instead of the Label, that should be able to receive focus.

Comment: Thanks greg,using text instead of label as the first control in composite,radio button is not selected by default. But there is a small issue,the cursor is blinking in the text which is not required since we are using that text just as a label purpose. So to ensure the same behaviour as RCP 3, is there any way to remove that cursor from text.

Comment: A blinking caret does not happen for me on macOS with SWT.READ_ONLY Text, but this may be platform specific. I don't know of a way to control that.